# How to avoid SST in Mariadb Galera

Tags: mysql, galera

I want to add a new node to galera without affecting existing node (donor). For example: node 1 is receive inserted data, and then node 2 join to cluster, node 1 is stuck and can't receive inserted data. How could I let node 1 receive inserted data continuously? Thanks!

Comment: If LVM is enabled and set up on the disk subsystem, there is a less-invasive way to get the second node established.

Answer (score 0):

note: ask database questions on https://dba.stackexchange.com/

A two node galera cluster is a fundamentally broken design for continuous uptime because of the same problem that you have now. A sst requires a node to go down.

As such to initialize without downtime and get to a 3 node scenario:

a) create a new node as a master-slave replica of your currently node. Ensure this node has 'log_slave_updates' configured.

b) create your galera node to use SST with the slave/replica node.

c) switch to using one of the galera nodes as the active node

d) change the async master to a galera node member where it will sync off one of the existing nodes (and the other should remain active).